# Addressing a Object-Function in an JavaScript Event-Handler

Tags: javascript, class, event-handling, this

let's say I have a JavaScript-Class like this:

```
Foo.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
      this.onKeyDown(event);
    });
  }

  onKeyDown: function(event) {
    alert("bar");
  }
}

myObj = new Foo();
myObj.init();
```

This Code won't work, because in

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    this.onKeyDown(event);
});
```

the 'this' is of course unknown and doesn't address the object. How can i address the onkeydown-method of the Foo-Class anyhow?

I don't want exchange 'this' with 'myObj' (the name of the Object) since i may want to use the class for other Objects aswell.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store it in a variable...

```
Foo.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
      self.onKeyDown(event);
    });
  }
}
```

or use `jQuery.proxy` to return a function with the `this` value bound...

```
Foo.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $(document).keydown( $.proxy(function(event) {
      this.onKeyDown(event);
    }, this) );
  }
}
```

or you can use `Function.prototype.bind`, but you'll need to patch it for older browsers.

```
Foo.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $(document).keydown( (function(event) {
      this.onKeyDown(event);
    }).bind(this) );
  }
}
```

- [Compatibility patch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) from MDN for `.bind()`